# How to alter session NLS_COMP/SORT after a perticular query is executed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, nls-comp

My question was specific to some problem scenario where Transaction being started from Spring Container by using `EntityManager` then I am getting hibernate session out of `EntityManager`.

## The overall flow:

1. In the application `entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchQuery)` is there to select some data.
2. I need to get the hibernate session out of `entityManager` then in the session I want to set `nls_comp`/`nls_sort` or I can execute the query in the `entityManager` itself. e.g. alter session set `nls_comp=linguistic`.
3. After its being done I want to disable these option once again back to its previous state. Most probably by closing the hibernate session or some mechanism. Is it the right approach?

Should I start another transaction for the 2 alter command also (I tried it gave some exception). Please let me know how to achieve it and how hibernate session are being managed inside a spring initiated transaction or I can achieve the enable/disable with `entityManager` itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
org.hibernate.Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {                 
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = LINGUISTIC");
            statement.addBatch("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT = SPANISH_M");
            statement.executeBatch();
        }
        finally {
            if(statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }           
        }                                
    }
});
```

1. You can get the Session from entityManager using getDelegate()
2. You can execute those two statements in the current associated connection
3. The changes are for the current database session only and when the connection is closed they should be restored to defaults. For connection pooling you have to check whether they get persisted.

You don't need to call session.close(), thins will be taken care of Spring automatically when closing the current Transaction. It's rare that you have to close the session manually.

If you want to execute a logic for the current settings, it's better to write an AOP aspect to execute 1. and 2. then let the call go through only to reset it back to the previous values in the finally block. You can define your own annotation to mark all the service methods you'd like to have this logic enabled. Spring pointcuts support annotation-based selection anyway.

Comment: That means if any other transaction is using the same connection they these changes will be reflected .I want this two settings to be reflected only for that session and that connection.So If I start a transaction and close it by doing (entityManager.getTransaction().begin()/commit()) or if I close the session which I got it from entityManager then these two setting will be gone and reset .Or else I have to again reset it back in that earlier transaction.Please clarify.

Comment: Two transactions won;t ever use the same JDBC connection simultaneously. To be on the safe side, go for the AOP aspect I mentioned in my updated response.

Comment: If the same connection is available to other transaction which value it will use.If I do select on NLS_PARAMETER then should it give the older or the new.I need to reset it back to the connection or close the connection so that it wont reflect in others.Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Vlad,I am not sure how to do with spring please give some reference.

Comment: How with Spring AOP above problem can be solved.Need your guidance.

Comment: Can I reset it back to the connection to original state or close the connection if its correct way by again calling session.dowork.