# Hibernate equivalent for skip_unusable_indexes (oracle)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have Java application that uses Spring JPA and Hibernate to connect to ORACLE 11g database.

From time to time, I need to `drop partition` in the DB and rebuild all the `UNUSABLE global indexes` to USABLE state. (The indexes become unusable due to drop partition command)

Between the time when my partition is dropped and UNUSABLE indexes are not yet rebuild, my online application fails with `ORA-01502 error` like below.

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01502: index 'USER.INDEX_NAME' or partition of such index is in unusable state

   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10070)
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
   at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
   ... 94 more
```

In SQL there is an option to ignore UNUSABLE indexes by setting `skip_unusable_indexes=TRUE`. This way query optimizer selects a different (expensive) execution plan that does not use index and does not report any failure on `DML` queries due to unusable indexes.

Is there any such similar option in Hibernate that I can use to not to fail when indexes are in UNUSABLE status?

Versions I am using
Hibernate: 3.6.9
Oracle: 11g
Java: 7

Answer (score 2):

You can rebuild the index:

```
ALTER INDEX USER.INDEX_NAME REBUILD;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes=true
```

like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669322/how-to-alter-session-nls-comp-sort-after-a-perticular-query-is-executed) but this session will be returned to the collection pool and reused so this will affect more than one query.

If I were you I would ask myself "Why my indexes are unusable?" This is a situation that should not happen unless you are executing some maintenance or executing some very large batch proccess. You may have a 24/7 system where you don't really wan't to stop the system for maintenance. In this case you can set the option system wise without a single change to your code. This way the system will be slower but behave nicer during maintenace. **Just remember that index used to enforce constrains can't be ignored and insert/update queries will fail anyway**. And add some automatic check that reports unusable indexes in PRO at certain times. Just a PL/SQL process that send emails can be OK

Another alternative is to change the option only during changes in the database:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET skip_unusable_indexes=true;
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP PARTITION P1; 
ALTER INDEX I1 REBUILD ONLINE
ALTER SYSTEM SET skip_unusable_indexes=false;
```

In [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128049/drop-partition-and-rebuild-global-indexes-online) there is a discussion about the better way to drop a partition. So you are not alone but the solution is for Oracle 12C.

Comment: As you said, indexes should never be in unusable state but unusable indexes are a tread off between locking tables while indexes are being built and allowing DMLs on the tables without using indexes in Oracle 11g. If I use a statement like `ALTER TABLE T1 DROP PARTITION P1 REBUILD GLOBAL INDEXES`, then my table gets locked until the index is rebuilt. But if I use 2 separate statements like  'ALTER TABLE T1 DROP PARTITION P1; ALTER INDEX I1 REBUILD ONLINE` then my DMLs are not blocked when index is being rebuilt. But unfortunately the hibernate inserts seems to fail due to unusable index error.

Comment: Why not: 
ALTER SYSTEM SET skip_unusable_indexes=true;
ALTER TABLE T1 DROP PARTITION P1; 
ALTER INDEX I1 REBUILD ONLINE;
ALTER SYSTEM SET skip_unusable_indexes=false;

Comment: Can you pls double check if skip_unusable_indexes can be modified at system level? Looks like as per [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/statements_22a.htm) `SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES is a session parameter only`

Comment: But starting with Oracle 10g you could use Alter System and of course is avalaible in your reported 11g version: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams229.htm

Comment: ah ha .. my bad. Let me check if that works ... thanks a lot for confirming.

Comment: Hi, it looks like all the system generated indexes (for example on primary key) are automatically unique in nature. And as per documentation if the index is enforcing unique constraint on the table, the DML operations will still fail as this setting does not disable error reporting on unique indexes. Is there any work around?

Comment: May be you could disable the primary key constraint... but do you really want to risk your database consistency? I believe that you may be better off asking in dba.stackexchange

Also see the new link answer